# Binomial Linear Model Fit Issues

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm a student working on a project for school and the example code I've been given to work with has a single linear model line (in blue) for the data set. Meanwhile, when I run the exact same code with my data it gives me *two* blue lines instead of just the one diagonal I want. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong/what the difference between my data and the example data set is. Any help at all would be appreciated!

Example code:

```
drunkdoor <- read_csv("https://uoepsy.github.io/data/drunkdoor.csv")
head(drunkdoor)
ggplot(drunkdoor, aes(x=age, y=notice)) + geom_point()+geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE, fullrange = TRUE) + xlim(30, 80)
```

[image: example data head + graph]

My code:

```
data1 <- read_csv('https://uoepsy.github.io/data/dapr2_2021_nullsit_data.csv')
head(data1)
ggplot(data1, aes(x = z_test, y = intervention1)) + geom_point() + geom_smoot(method = "lm)
```

[image: my data head + graph]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is that in the example plot, they are using numeric values for `y` while you are using character values. One way around that is to specify the "group" value so ggplot knows which sets of points should be in the same line. If you use `group=1` in the `aes()` it will know to group all points together and draw one line (rather than one line for each character value)

```
ggplot(data1, aes(x = z_test, y = intervention1, group=1)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(method = "lm")
```

Alternatively you could change the values to numeric values

```
ggplot(data1, aes(x = z_test, y = ifelse(intervention1=="control",0,1))) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(method = "lm")
```

Note that the two lines are different because it puts the values in a different order on the y axis. You would need to decide if you want "control" on top or "control" on bottom.